# Mocha, should.js, and Promise catch callback

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, should.js

I am trying to assert a proper error message in an async promise failure test with mocha, but my test is not passing and I don't know why.

Here's the code - the promise is

```
'use strict';

let getFailingPromise = function() {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    // simply fail on the next tick
    setTimeout(function() {

      reject(new Error('No reason.'));
    });
  });
}

describe('failing promise catcher', function() {

  it('should fail and I should catch it', function(done) {

    let promise = getFailingPromise();
    promise.catch(function(err) {

      console.log('Error message:', err.message); // => Error message: No reason.
      console.log(err.message === 'No reason.');  // => true
      err.message.should.equal('No reason.');
      done();                                     // => Never reached.
    });
  });
});
```

I know about Mocha not being able to catch async exceptions. But the code above is all clean, no errors are thrown - or there shouldn't be any.

*Edit:* Adding output of the call:

```
[zlatko@obelix ~/tmp]$ mocha test.spec.js 


  failing promise catcher
Error message: No reason.
true
    1) should fail and I should catch it


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) failing promise catcher should fail and I should catch it:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at null.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:158:19)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:89:15)
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: log your typeof err.message, see if it's an object , bro

Comment: With latest mocha you can just return promise from test and do not need to add done callback. If you tell `done()` not reached, you must see error, right? Which one?

Comment: I know I can return a promise. I wanna assert properties of the error that I get from a rejected call, that's why I am doing it. And I've shown the error, lemme show the whole output.

Comment: @KevinSimple it's a string - see the tripple equal in that `err.message === 'No reason.'`?

Comment: @Zlatko What `Promise` implementation are you using?

Comment: Just try to add another `.catch(console.error.bind(console))`

Comment: Using native promises here in this example, Node 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not loading `should` to implement `err.message.should.equal()`, so an exception is thrown by the runtime.

Generally, exceptions thrown within a `.catch()` will be ignored unless you add another `.catch()` clause to your promise chain (as @Bergi suggests in the comments).

Another option would be to use a more elaborate promises implementation that would warn you about unhandled rejections, like [`bluebird`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html), which would have shown you this:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined
at ...
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Now gotta go build another minimal example, see why my actual code fails. Another catch hook suggested by Bergi will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
promise.catch(function(err) {
  done(err.message !== 'No reason.' ? new Error('Failed') : undefined);                                     // => Never reached.
});
```